# Windows shortcut. Nested argument not being read

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, shortcut

I cannot get the shortcut below to work:

```
C:\Windows\System32\ForceBindIP.exe x.x.x.x "C:\Program Files (x86)\Comodo\Dragon\dragon.exe" -user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11"
```

The user-agent part is not being read correctly, it just causes the browser to open new tabs with parts of the string itself.

How should the shortcut look like? I've tried to make it run run as batch files, tried escape characters in PS, but failed.

Answer (score 3):

Found this just from searching Google. 
http://old.r1ch.net/forum/index.php?topic=1310.0

It sounds like the first parameter is not passed to your program but the subsequent arguments are, so just make a dummy argument.

```
C:\Windows\System32\ForceBindIP.exe x.x.x.x "C:\Program Files (x86)\Comodo\Dragon\dragon.exe" dummy -user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/535.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11"
```

Comment: @crun could you please mark this as answered.  Thanks much. http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers